# How to tag the Need for Speed games?

Tags: discussion, tags

We currently have:

- [nfsmw](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfsmw) ×6
- [need-for-speed-world](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-world) ×3
- [need-for-speed-hp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-hp) ×2
- [need-for-speed-mw](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-mw) ×2

I think this makes it self evident that we should rather tag our games:

- [nfs-most-wanted](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs-most-wanted)
- [nfs-world](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs-world)
- [nfs-hot-pursuit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs-hot-pursuit)

Thoughts?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Given that `need-for-speed-most-wanted` is yet another game name which blows past the 25 character tag limit, I'd say we should encourage the `nfs` abbreviation. It's a well known abbreviation for the series anyway, and we should be able to make synonyms for the full name versions.

Comment: Exactly 26 again. My Grace Note senses are tingling.

Answer (score 2):

I actually much prefer the tagging style of:

- [need-for-speed-world](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-world)
- [need-for-speed-hp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-hp)
- [need-for-speed-mw](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-mw)

Over tags starting with "nfs", because:

1. It is consistent with other tags already used - or at least, with many tags I know of.
2. The most important part of a tag is its beginning, because of auto-complete. So I really want a need-for-speed game to start with need-for-speed. And for users who are choosing those tags the otherwise cryptic "hp" or "mw" abbreviations become obvious, since they are limited to the need-for-speed domain.
3. The NFS series is relatively well-known and probably has very few other games competing with the initials, but other gaming abbreviations may not be unique, so I think it's best to start with the full name.

I admit, though, that many nfs players are very likely to use the initials as well, so it might be wise to set up synonyms.

Comment: nfsmw has 6 posts, need-for-speed-mw has 2. The numbers are so low it's silly to pull facts out of them, though.