# Tag merge request: nfs-hot-pursuit and need-for-speed-hp

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

I don't have the rep needed to suggest synonyms, but [nfs-hot-pursuit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs-hot-pursuit) (9 questions) and [need-for-speed-hp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-hp) (6 questions) refer to the same game and I think they should be merged. It seems like most NFS games are tagged as `need-for-speed-[game]`, so I vote for keeping [need-for-speed-hp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-hp) as the master tag and merging the other one into it.

Comment: We [never did settle this one](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/how-to-tag-the-need-for-speed-games)...

Comment: @Grace Fair enough. I'm not particular about which way it goes... :) But maybe after 5 months one consistent approach can be picked? Looks like nfs-blah got more of the votes and the reasoning seems sound. If retagging/renaming all of the tags is too much, then can we at least merge two different ones that mean the same game?

Comment: I'm fine with picking one and then doing this merge. I definitely don't think we should let this last longer than today.

Comment: I like `nfs-blah` as well, NFS is a familiar acronym for me.  `hp` makes me think there was a weird Harry Potter crossover.

Comment: Yeah, `nfs-game-name-spelled-out` seems more natural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good catch; synonym created. I went [with the majority](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/how-to-tag-the-need-for-speed-games) and made the master tag [nfs-hot-pursuit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs-hot-pursuit) as, while there should be little doubt as to what "NFS" means (in context), "HP" is a much more obscure abbreviation.

Comment: That said, reverting the direction is quite simple.

Answer (score 3):

I am not a Need for Speed player, but [need-for-speed-xyz](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-xyz) seems backward to me. NFS is a fairly well-recognized abbreviation. Abbreviations like "HP" and "MW" seem far more ambiguous.

To me, it seems logical to use the full part of the name *that is unique to the game* (e.g. "Hot Pursuit" or "Most Wanted") and abbreviate the element "Need for Speed", which is common to them all. Especially if [need-for-speed-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-series) is also going to be used.

On the other hand, [need-for-speed-hp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-hp) might be a little more discoverable for a user just trying stuff in the tag field to see what pops up.