# Tag rename request [nfs2se] -> [need-for-speed-2-se]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

I just noticed [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/308794/is-there-anything-to-unlock) and saw the [nfs2se](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs2se) tag, so I went to see what it was, because from that tag name, it is not obvious what game is being talked about at all. The question itself had to explain what the tag stood for, but I don't think a question using a tag should have to do that.

Since it would actually fit in under 25 characters, I think [need-for-speed-2-se](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-2-se) would make more sense and look a lot better than [nfs2se](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs2se).

However, this tag already has a tag wiki written for it and I'd hate to erase the work put into that by just editing that question to have the new tag. Would it be possible to transfer the tag wiki to a new [need-for-speed-2-se](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-2-se) tag via a tag rename? The existing [nfs2se](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs2se) could even be a synonym of this tag if people wanted that; I just don't think it's necessary to abbreviate the base tag to that degree.

Comment: Besides the SE part, I usually make the connection that NFS in terms of gaming means Need for Speed - that being said, I do like more descriptive tags as suggested by you.

Comment: I think it is a good idea to be as consistent as possible on tagging conventions, however we aren't all that consistent with nfs tags. See [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2184/tag-merge-request-nfs-hot-pursuit-and-need-for-speed-hp?rq=1) we created the tag [tag:nfs-hot-pursuit] as the main tag with [tag:need-for-speed-hp] the synonym. We are fairly split on which convention to use, but the tags that have both use nfs-xxxxx as the master and use need-for-speed-xxxxx as the synonym. I would say we should change all to use nfs-xxxx as master as nfs is a common abbreviation.

Comment: @Dragonrage I didn't look into the other tags, but agree with consistency. I'd prefer expanding the series name and then abbreviating the individual titles, but if the majority prefers the abbreviated series name, that's fine. Though, I still would have been confused by [nfs-2-special-edition], but maybe less so.

Comment: @Vemonus i typically prefer spelling the series name out and abbreviating the game name, as people who are typing the tag in typically are going to type need..... as opposed to nfs imo. maybe we should make a separate meta to establish the tagging convention for nfs series

Comment: found this meta relating to tagging convention https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/how-to-tag-the-need-for-speed-games

Comment: @Dragonrage huh, well, either way, this tag abbreviated *both* parts and is in need of renaming, then. I'd still advocate spelling out the series and abbreviating the individual title, though.

Comment: @Vemonus as would I. it is the typical naming convention we use across most tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the [recent tag length increase](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12497/increase-tag-length-limit-to-32-or-35)* I've actioned this and changed the tag to [need-for-speed-2-special-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-2-special-edition). The tag excerpt came along with the rename/merge.

<sub>* Please report any display issues or page errors with 26+ character long tags as a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) on Meta.</sub>